Improve multiple options layout
This is a section in Settings page, I want to enhance the UX design. I want convert it to tables, but it becomes confusing. What will be a better approach?

I want ideas to enhance UX design for the attached image it is section in the setting page control search for different category (Search for stock item, search for customer, search for accounts, search for cost center) and every category has options and every option (has option match or like)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I want ideas to enhance UX design for the attached image
it is section in the setting page control search for different category (Search for stock item, search for customer, search for accounts, search for cost center)
and every category has options and every option (has option match or like)

You should start by taking a look at the Settings page for MacOS, iOS or Android systems. This problem looks similar to them.
